# Characterisation of network of nonlinear resistors

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

I have an electrical network made out of nodes and wires. Constant voltage supplies with a shared ground are attached to all nodes and consumers are attached to nodes which take out a constant current $d$ (for demand). I am interested in the steady state of this system. The resistance of the wires is non linear. The wires are passive.

Between the nodes i and j the equation is

$$u_i + u_{s,i} -u_j -u_{s,j} = R_{nl}(|I_{i \rightarrow j}|)$$ where $u_i$ are the voltages at nodes, $u_{s,i}$ are the constant voltage sources attached to nodes with shared ground, $R_{nl}$ is the non-linear resistors voltage drop at a given current $I_{i \rightarrow j}$.

$R_{nl}(I)$ is symmetric and $R_{nl}(0 A) = 0V$. This function is otherwise unknown.

Can i calculate given $u_{s,i}$, the connection graph and $d_i$ the steady state power loss over the unknown non linear resistors?

If i can't can i put a bound the power loss?

If i can't what other additional information would i need to make those calculations?

Comment: A circuit diagram would help me understand your post. For example, $u_{\rm i}$ is the potential difference between which two nodes?